# Problemilla con Python y Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python

estoy leyendome un libro: "Aprende Machine Learning en Español" y estoy experimentando un error en la consola de Anaconda que también está relacionado con Python, estoy siguiendo los ejercicios y debería tener instalado algo entiendo por el mensaje de error que me da, que es el siguiente: "python versiones.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\anton\versiones.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tengo que escribir un archivo de texto para escribir un breve script de Python, pero por ejemplo en el primer código tengo que escribir: import scipy. y este ultimo me lo subraya como error, entonces pruebo en la consola para ver si está instalado y me da el mensaje de error que os he escrito.
Voy a seguir buscando una solución por la red pero no sé donde estoy fallando.

Edito: ya instale los paquetes antes (supongo porque instale lo que decía el libro todo Anaconda, supongo que está instalado pero como me da error no sé. "Voy un poco perdido la verdad"),, siguiendo los pasos del libro. Los he vuelto a instalar para estar seguro, en la consola de Anaconda.

Muchísimas gracias y saludos mis brothers!

Comment: El archivo no existe `C:\Users\anton\versiones.py` ... ¿lo revistaste?

Comment: versiones.py está en otra carpeta, en esa ruta no está (no lo tengo guardado ahí) no sé por que lo busca en esa carpeta. Y gracias por decirmelo, no me había fijado en eso, voy a cambiarlo de carpeta haber si lo soluciono. Thanks!

Comment: He colocado el archivo en la carpeta donde lo buscaba (ahora lo ha encontrado) y me da el siguiente error: "(base) C:\Users\anton>python versiones.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anton\versiones.py", line 2, in <module>
    print ("scipy: %s" %scipy._version_)
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute '_version_'".
Y eso porque no he acabado de escribir el código ya que me subraya por ejemplo: el scipy, como error y ya no sigo escribiendo hasta que solucione el error porque escribí más pero me lo subrrayaba como error.